# PHP sanitize email from a Wordpress form

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm writing a plugin which calls an API and uses an email address as part of the authentication.

I'm getting really confused regarding which way round parts of my code should go in terms of variables, and as such keep getting undefined variable errors.

This function outputs a form on a Worpdress admin page and allows the user to input their email address. I wish to sanitise the email after it has been input, then spit back out the sanitised version into the input field.

```
function dotmailer_options() {
?>

    <div class="wrap">
        <h2>Dotmailer API information</h2>
        <form method="post" action="options.php">
        <?php settings_fields( 'settings-group' ); ?>
        <?php do_settings_sections( 'settings-group' ); ?>
            <label>API key</label><br />
            <input type="email" name="apiemail" value="<?php echo $sanitized_email; ?>"><br />
            <label>Password</label><br />
            <input type="password" name="apipassword" value="<?php echo get_option('apipassword'); ?>"><br />
            <p><input type="submit" value="Save" class="button-primary" /></p>
            <?php
            // Store email field as var
            $apiemail = get_option('apiemail');
            // Sanitize var
            $sanitized_email = filter_var($apiemail, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
            ?>
        </form>
    </div>
```

However when I do this I get an "undefined" error actually in the input box.

I understand this is probably because the code to create `$sanitized_email` runs after the input has called for it, but I can't work out how else I should do this.

Also will having code directly in this function open me up to attacks? I have the following at the top of my plugin code: `defined('ABSPATH') or die();` - but I don't know if that is enough.

Comment: is `apiemail` present in db table `options` with a valid email

Comment: you'll have to set a variable so the function knows whether it is a first time display or things have been processed already.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to use either javascript or ajax for this as php is server code rather than browser code (i.e. it runs on the serverside only) whilst javascript is browser code and can re-act to changes in the browser.

But there is no point in sanitizing at this stage, but you would of course sanitize and validate the form submission $_POST items. If displaying variable information from $_POST or the database to the user, you escape the values before inputting them into html.

You could validate the email using javascript to speed things up for the user if there is an issue..

```
<script>
function validateEmail() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["apiemail"].value;
    var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
  if (atpos< 1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length) {
    document.elements["apiemail"].value = "Invalid email";
    return false;
  }
}
</script>
```

and in your form:

```
<input type="email" name="apiemail" value="" onchange="validateEmail()">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason you're getting an undefined error is you haven't defined the variable in advance - Try putting…

```
$sanitized_email = "";
```

in before your form processing code.

Also, are you using some form of checking if the form has been set or not? You can use a hidden field and check if_isset using php to see if the user has attempted to process the form. Only then would the sanitized variable be needed.